# How to sort array or arraylist of objects in java (containing suppose 10 objects ) in the order of say age

Tags: java

I was a C programmer so I am new to Java and I was looking for a way to sort the arrays of objects I have created or maybe arraylist of objects (say of 10 objects)

I have been searching over the Internet but I got only comparison of two objects at a time on the basis of age(say) but none are for 10 objects.
I tried using bubble sort but I am unable to change the order of objects in arraylist or array like I used to do in C.

Well geocodezip suggested the use of Collections.sort but I am getting compile time error

int cannot be dereferenced.

```
class Party
{
int count=0;
String name=null;
public static Comparator<Party> COMPARE_BY_COUNT =new Comparator<Party>()
{
public int compare( Party p,Party other)
 {
 return p.count.compareTo(other.count);
      }
     };

}
void bubsort(ArrayList<Party>partieslist)

{
//List<Party> partieslist=new ArrayList<Party>();
    Collections.sort(partieslist,Party.COMPARE_BY_COUNT) ;
}
```

Comment: This one returns an integer after comparing only 2 values how can we sort multiple objects using it?

Comment: `Collections.sort` (as described in the answer to that question).

Comment: It's not compiling error shown is int cannot be derefenced...

Comment: Can anyone help how can I attach code snippet to my program

Comment: Probably `Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge))`.

Comment: The posted code looks wrong.

Comment: Here now as suggested by @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic I made changes to my program but it's showing error

Comment: Why are you closing this question? I have been trying for hours on end trying to find my error and rectify it and I have been repeatedly saying that the given answer does NOT answer my query as I am getting error of int cannot be derefenced... Even the given suggestions are not working propely. What am I to do if my question gets closed so soon?

Comment: Did you check the answer to the question linked to your questions? The answer explains it clearly.

Comment: Yes I checked the answers but can you please debug the above attached program. I can't seem to find my error

Comment: I see that no one is interested to debug this program. Why may I know please? Is it too tough to debug ? Can any of you give any hints at least how to debug? I simply have no idea. Like why close such a tough question? It should feel quite challenging to be able to debug for great programmers.

Comment: My prof was right..

Comment: Out of curiosity: why not debug that little program on your own? Even if you are just learning Java, it should not be too hard, and it's well documented (for example at https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/june/article1.php)

Comment: It's a program that I myself wrote @Nico Haase so how can I debug it myself?

Comment: and I don't have eclipse IDE since my prof said that in the beginner stages I should not be using IDE as it would spoil my chance to learn JAVA